# Undo removal of GameObject with AddComponent script in Unity Editor (Play mode)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, editor, undo-redo

Here's a very specific question I've been struggling to answer. I have a simple script that creates/destroys a component during awake/destroy in run time:

```
// Simple script that creates and destroys an AudioSource component in runtime.
public class SimpleScript : MonoBehaviour {
  // Runtime AudioSource component to be used.
  private AudioSource source = null;

  void Awake() {
    source = gameObject.AddComponent<AudioSource>();
    source.hideFlags = HideFlags.HideAndDontSave;
  }

  void OnDestroy() {
    Destroy(source);
  }

  void Update() {
    // Do stuff with |source| . . .
  }
}
```

It works perfectly fine with build exports and everything, however, I've recently noticed a very specific case where Unity acts a bit strangely. In Unity Editor (Play mode), if I remove this script (or the game object that the script is attached to), then undo the operation, it results in two [AudioSource](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource.html)s attached to the resurrected game object. More specifically; one destroyed by my script previously with the remove operation + one created with the new [Awake](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Awake.html) call. And as expected, doing this repeatedly creates more and more *leaked* components.

Using different [HideFlags](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/HideFlags.html) to disable (?) serialization doesn't seem to do any good, nor trying [DestroyImmediate](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DestroyImmediate.html) etc. for destroying the component. My understanding here is that Unity treats the manually created component as one of [GameObject](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.html)'s components, hence registers the destroy and undoes it alongside undoing the script removal.

Any suggestions on how to bypass/avoid this strange behaviour of Unity?

Cheers!

Comment: If you're recreating the GameObject, why not just disable and re-enable it?

Comment: The problem here is that you don't have the component in the first place, i.e., you have to create it somewhere in the script anyway so that you could enable/disable it. :)

Answer (score 1):

You answered your question yourself, @anokta!
The `Awake()` method creates an AudioSource-- i.e. will create it each time the owning game-object is created.
Now when you delete the object from the hierarchy view manually (i.e. click > delete, etc), and then *undo* it, you are calling a purely Editor mechanic of re-creating that last delete. That will essentially re-create the object that existed (game-object with the added `AudioSource`). And because this is now a new object that's been created, it will automatically immediately execute its `Awake()` method again.

I'm sure you knew this already and were probably looking for a way around. Deleting objects in editor manually at run-time is a touchy area, and there's endless weird behaviour that can be created with that.

If you really wanted to constrain it, how about setting a flag elsewhere (in a global-manager perhaps) that is turned on as soon as the `AddComponent<AudioSource>();` is called? i.e.

```
void Awake() {
    if (globalManager.AsCreated != true)
    {
        source = gameObject.AddComponent<AudioSource>();
        source.hideFlags = HideFlags.HideAndDontSave;
        globalManager.AsCreated = true;
    }
}
```

where `globalManager` is ...a global-manager of some sort. This way, you could delete the object at runtime (which I still assert can cause endless weird behaviour) and still undo for the result you want.
I hope that helps!

Comment: Sadly agreed, maybe it is *okay* to let this happen after all. I guess the global flag workaround might get messy when multiple instances etc. are involved. Apart from that, one other workaround I can think of right now is to check GetComponent before adding the component. Of course, that would restrict us to one component per game object then - that IMO is even less *okay*. :)